# Save Array Data into Database without duplicate

Tags: php, phpmyadmin

Showing data correctly into array.
Now want to push into database(phpmyadmin>attendance).
any idea how to push data into database without duplicating.(ignore duplicate entry into database.

**code**

```
foreach($output_array as $uid => $data)
    {
        echo
        '
            <tr>
                <td>'.$uid.'</td>
                <td>'.(isset($data["name"]) && !empty($data["name"]) ? $data["name"] : "N/A").'</td>

                <td>'.(isset($data['Check In']) && !empty($data['Check In']) ? $data['Check In'] : "N/A").'</td>
                <td>'.(isset($data["checkout"]) && !empty($data["checkout"]) ? $data["checkout"] : "N/A").'</td>
            </tr>
        ';
    }
```

**Result**

```
-----------------------------
| Name   | TimeIn | TimeOut |
-----------------------------
| John   | 2:00   | 5:00    |
| Kings  | 1:00   | 3:00    |
-----------------------------
```

**Database Column**

```
id | Name | Time
```

**Php**

```
$datapush = json_encode($output_array);
$sql = "INSERT INTO attendance (id, name, time) VALUES ('$datapush')";
```

Answer (score 0):

MySql understands SQL query only and MySql does not support direct insertion of php arrays
So convert php array into MySql sql statement but one row can insert at a time.

In this code, your $output_array may be

```
Array
(
    [101] => Array
        (
            [name] => John
            [Check In] => 2.00
            [checkout] => 5.00
        )

    [102] => Array
        (
            [name] => Kings
            [Check In] => 1.00
            [checkout] => 3.00
        )

    [103] => Array
        (
            [name] => Manick
            [Check In] => 3.30
            [checkout] => 4.40
        )

    [104] => Array
        (
            [name] => John
            [Check In] => 1.50
            [checkout] => 3.30
        )

)
```

It has sub array values. Duplicate checking process can implement only by writing manual coding and not use "in_array()" because
"in_array() " does not check duplicate values in sub array.

Try this code..

```
$temp_array = [];

foreach($output_array as $uid => $data)
{
    echo
    '
        <tr>
            <td>'.$uid.'</td>
            <td>'.(isset($data["name"]) && !empty($data["name"]) ? $data["name"] : "N/A").'</td>

            <td>'.(isset($data['Check In']) && !empty($data['Check In']) ? $data['Check In'] : "N/A").'</td>
            <td>'.(isset($data["checkout"]) && !empty($data["checkout"]) ? $data["checkout"] : "N/A").'</td>
        </tr>
    ';

    if (!check_duplicate($data['name'], $temp_array))
    {
        $array_push = ['id' => $uid, 'name' => $data['name'], 'Time' => $data['Check In']];
        $sql = "INSERT INTO attendance (id, name, time) VALUES ('".implode("','",$array_push)."')";    

        // Execute Sql Query
        mysql_query($sql);

        // Store Array values in Temporary Array for checking duplicates
        array_push($temp_array, $array_push);
    }

}

function check_duplicate($key, $arr)
{
    foreach($arr as $arr_1)
    {
        if(in_array($key, $arr_1))
            return TRUE;
    }

    return FALSE;
}
```

This example checks "name" has duplicate values and insert "check in" time value to Time field value

Comment: its pushing only last and 1 record into database.